# How to add new product to particular customer's wishlist in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, wishlist, customer-group

Can anyone help me out? I want to add new products to the **particular customer's wishlist automatically**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php   
  $customerId = 2;
  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $productCollection = $objectManager- >create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');

 $collection = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
  ->setPageSize(3)
  ->addAttributeToSort('updated_at', 'DESC')
  ->load();

 foreach($collection as $product){

$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product->getId());


$wishList = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistFactory');

$wishlistAdd = $wishList->create()->loadByCustomerId($customerId, true);
$wishlistAdd->addNewItem($product);
$wishlistAdd->save();

}

?>
```

I **highly recommend** to inject   `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product` and `Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistFactory` in your constructor.

This is for your just quick snippet.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: while using this code in template file i am getting this error."Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$objectManagerr' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento223\app\code\Wishorder\Asorder\view\frontend\templates\asorder.phtml on line 7" ---Please help me out

Comment: Update your question with your code, So that i can help you out.

Comment: the code you provided that only i have added in custom module template..nothing new i added

Comment: Please paste properly, :) You messed up with `$objectManager`.
There's `$objectmanagerr` in your error. :)

Comment: the same one i tried after only i tried with objectManagerr..that too i got error

Comment: Paste your PHTML file code here.

Comment: second line was not completed with ';'..so i got error..now i got ..thank you...and how the new products can be added to particular customer's wishlist automatically?

Comment: Check my updated code, Let me know if it works.

Comment: If it works for you, Accept answer and up vote it to help community.

Comment: Sql error appearing on additem function

Answer (score 0):

You have use `Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist` class.

First you need to *load a customer* **wishlist** by calling  function [`loadByCustomerId()`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Wishlist/Model/Wishlist.php#L193)

Then add a new item to wish list using method [`addNewItem`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Wishlist/Model/Wishlist.php#L391)

### Code:

```
<?php
namespace {NameSpaceofClass};
class {Classname}{

    protected $_wishlistFactory;

    public function __construct(
         \Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistFactory $wishlistFactory
    )
    {
       $this->_wishlistFactory = $wishlistFactory
    }

    public function addAnewProduct()
    {
        $wishlist = $this->_wishlistFactory->create();

        $wishlist->loadByCustomerId(15); //15 is Customer Id

        if($wishlist){
                $wishlist->addNewItem(25); // 25 Product id
        }
    }
}
```

**Note that:**

**addNewItem has  3 parameters**

1. `$product` can `Product id OR product object` which
   should be instance `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product`.
2. `$buyRequest` , it should be instance

   \Magento\Framework\DataObject
       or array or string or null

.
 3. `$forciblySetQty`  boolean true/false forcefully set qty.

Comment: where I need to use this code..in block or controller?

Comment: You can call this at any where you want to use

Comment: while using this code in block file i didnt get anything in the frontend. and its not adding the product to wishlish

Comment: You need to make your block class not cache . OR You should add  code at controller

Comment: while putting in controller file, i am getting the error like this..

Comment: "Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Wishorder\Asorder\Controller\Index\Index::__construct(), 2 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento223\generated\code\Wishorder\Asorder\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor.php on line 14 and exactly 3 expected in

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\magento223\app\code\Wishorder\Asorder\Controller\Index\Index.php:15 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento223\generated\code\Wishorder\Asorder\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor.php(14): Wishorder\Asorder\Controller\Index\Index->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory)) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento223\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(111):

Comment: Wishorder\Asorder\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory)) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento223\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(66): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Fac in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento223\app\code\Wishorder\Asorder\Controller\Index\Index.php on line 15".....last three comments are my error

Comment: Please share u controller code .I am sure you have some mistake at __construct function

Comment: please look into that ..i put the controller code in answer

Comment: hey...please look into my controller code..and make changes

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I have used in my controller

```
  <?php
     namespace Wishorder\Asorder\Controller\Index;

      use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
      use   \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory ;
      use   \Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistFactory ;

      class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
      {

        protected $resultPageFactory;
        protected $wishlistFactory;

        public function __construct(Context $context
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory, 
        \Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistFactory $wishlistFactory
        )
       {
          $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
          $this->wishlistFactory = $wishlistFactory;
          parent::__construct($context);
       }
public function execute()
{
    $wishlist = $this->wishlistFactory->create();

    $wishlist->loadByCustomerId(1); //15 is Customer Id
    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    if($wishlist){
            $wishlist->addNewItem(25); // 25 Product id
            $wishlist->save(); // 25 Product id     
    }
    return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
}
}
?>
```